# Why did my while loop fail when I defined the break code?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and was exploring a simple side project to understand how functions and loops work.

I have this code right here

```
age = 0

def ageInMonths (age):
    months =  int(age) * 12
    return print('You are ' + str(months) + ' months old!')

def ageInDays(age):
     days = int(age)*365
     return print('You are ' + str(days) + ' days old!')

def ageInHrs(age):
    hrs = int(age)* 8765.81
    return print('You are ' + str(hrs) + ' hours old!')

    def ageinMin(age):
       minutes = int(age)* 525948.8
       return print('You are ' + str(minutes) + ' minutes old!')

    def ageinSec(age):
       sec= int(age)* 31556926
       return print('You are ' + str(sec) + ' seconds old!')


def agePrint(age):
    age=age
    ageInMonths(age)
    ageInDays(age)
    ageInHrs(age)
    ageinMin(age)
    ageinSec(age)
      print('Done')
    return 

while age != 99:

    print( 'Please enter your age?')

    age = input()
    if age == 99:
     break


    print('You are ' + age + ' years old!')


    agePrint(age)
```

Every time I enter 99 the while loop does not break.  Any suggestions to where I went wrong..

Comment: `input` returns an `str` and `99` is an `int`, so they are not the same.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot to convert the input to `int`:

```
age = int(input())
```

If you don't do that explicitly, `age` will be a string, and naturally `'99' != 99`.

Comment: Thank you that helped out a lot.